# Is it possible to scatter points inside of an object?

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes, geometry, procedural

Inside of Houdini it is possible to distribute points inside of an object by first converting it to a volume object then scattering points inside of it, is it possible to achieve this within geometry nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a native dedicated node for it yet, but there are other options. A native solution was in the works, which was [abandoned](https://developer.blender.org/D12636) first, then [picked up again](https://developer.blender.org/D12636) later. It's possible we'll see it soon enough, but there's no apparent timeline for it.

In the meantime, there are many tutorials and presets/ready to use node groups produced by different users for the job. Here's a tutorial [by Bradley Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvb2aCeTANM) which does randomized distribution, and here's another tutorial [by Entagma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8pI_f-S6bg) which does a more regular grid packing. There's also the possibility that instead of creating native nodes for too many operations, some will be distributed with Blender as node groups in an asset bundle. There's a development thread for it, which includes a ready to use preset [by Erindale](https://developer.blender.org/T95445#1310553) (if you wanna just download and use immediately without bothering with tutorials, I'd recommend this one).